# Why does my service not persist a domain object?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have a service which should persist simple domain objects.

```
class EventService {
    def logEventLogin(SecUser secUser) {
        Event event = new Event(secUser: secUser, eventDate: new Date());
        event.save();
    }

        ...
```

When I debug, I can see code reach `event.save()` but nothing happens at `event.save();`  My expectation is that it should be persisted.

No exception is throw.  I turn on hibernate logging and there is nothing there either.

Any tips?

Comment: try to add a validate check to it first and determine if there are any errors before you do the actual save.


    if(event.validate()) {
        event.save(flush:true)
    else {
        event.errors.allErrors.each { println it }
    }

Comment: Or use`failOnError` during save.

Comment: You probably fell in the save() trap! =) I suggest reading [GORM Gotchas](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Change the `event.save()` call to this:

```
event.save(failOnError:true, flush: true)
```

Adding `failOnError: true` will tell you if you have any validation errors that are preventing the `event` from being persisted. Adding `flush: true` will force the object to persist to the database immediately (instead of waiting for the next Hibernate flush). Try adding both of these and see if you can find the issue from there.

[Here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) is more information on saves in Grails.